# Incorrect data in a Fortran array after reading

Tags: fortran

```
! This is my code, but I don't get true  theta's result
program random
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    real :: T_i(27),P_i(27),theta

 ! ==================Read T_data and P_data===============
    print*,'==========This is temperature  T :====================='
    read (*,200)T_i(27)
    200 format(F7.3)
    print*,'==========This is pressure  P :====================='
    read (*,200)P_i(27)
    print*,'This is output of 1: 27'
    print*,T_i(1:27)
    print*,P_i(1:27)


! =======================Start work out==================
! start
    do i=1,27    
    ! formula:                                    
        theta = (T_i(i)) * (1000.0/(P_i(i)))** 0.286
        print*,'======',i,'==================='
        write(*,100)theta
        100 format('theta值为:',F6.2)  
    enddo
end
```

This is result

[image]

it has many inf and 0.00

I don't know why.

Comment: What are some sample value for pressure and temperature?

Comment: Why do you have `read (*,200)T_i(27)` to read in just one element of the array, when you later try to use values of all elements? Please explain more about what you are wanting, including the structure of your input file.

Comment: Thank you  , the problem has been resolved
I've learned a lot from you, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The read statement `read (*,200)T_i(27)` only reads 1 value into the 27th index. I think what you want is `read (*,200)T_i(1:27)`

More complete solution below:

```
! This is my code, but I don't get true  theta's result
program random
    implicit none
    integer :: i
    real :: T_i(27),P_i(27),theta

 ! ==================Read T_data and P_data===============
    print*,'==========This is temperature  T :====================='
    read (*,*)T_i(1:27)
    print*,'==========This is pressure  P :====================='
    read (*,*)P_i(1:27)
    print*,'This is output of 1: 27'
    print*,T_i(1:27)
    print*,P_i(1:27)


! =======================Start work out==================
! start
    do i=1,27    
    ! formula:                                    
        theta = (T_i(i)) * (1000.0/(P_i(i)))** 0.286
        print*,'======',i,'==================='
        write(*,100)theta
        100 format('theta值为:',F6.2)  
    enddo
end
```

---

I can suggest some small improvements for cleaner code. Use an `elemental` function to do the math on the entire array. Also, use `parameter` for the size of the array. ALso the input can be of general formatting so that it does not try to cast integer inputs as floats resulting in incorrect values.

```
    program FortranProgram1
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

! This is my code, but I don't get true  theta's result
    integer, parameter :: count = 27
    integer :: i
    real :: T_i(count),P_i(count),theta(count)

 ! ==================Read T_data and P_data===============
    print*,'==========This is temperature  T :====================='
    read (*, *) T_i
200 format(F7.3)
    print*,'==========This is pressure  P :====================='
    read (*, *) P_i
    print '(a,g0)', 'This is output of 1:',count
    print*, T_i
    print*, P_i


! =======================Start work out==================
! start
    theta = f(T_i,P_i)
    do i=1,count    
        print*,'======',i,'==================='
        write(*,100) theta(i)
100     format('theta值为:',F6.2)  
    enddo

    contains
    
    elemental function f(T,P) result(U)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: T,P
    real :: U
        U = T * (1000.0/P) ** 0.286
    end function

    end program
```

```text
 ==========This is temperature  T :=====================
20
25
30
40
60
 ==========This is pressure  P :=====================
1023
1034
1076
1085
1093
This is output of 1:5
   20.00000       25.00000       30.00000       40.00000       60.00000
   1023.000       1034.000       1076.000       1085.000       1093.000
 ======           1 ===================
thetaσÇ╝Σ╕║: 19.87
 ======           2 ===================
thetaσÇ╝Σ╕║: 24.76
 ======           3 ===================
thetaσÇ╝Σ╕║: 29.38
 ======           4 ===================
thetaσÇ╝Σ╕║: 39.08
 ======           5 ===================
thetaσÇ╝Σ╕║: 58.49
```